# Can javascript set attributes like links and a title based on an ID of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, image-gallery

I'm building an image gallery with 600 thumbnail photos.  All the thumbnails are the same size and they should all behave in the same way.  Clicking on a thumbnail will bring up a small version of the image and there's an image magnifier called jQZoom that will let visitors see the photo in more detail.  ( http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/ )

Here's the code I'm using for a typical thumbnail (number 462):

```
<a  href='javascript:void(0);' title="Plate 462" rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './Vol4/Small/tafel_462.jpg',largeimage: './Vol4/Large/tafel_462.jpg'}">
<img src="Vol4/Thumbs/tafel_462.jpg" width="94" height="150" border="0" /></a>
```

The problem is that it seems like a lot of code for what I'm trying to do.  In particular, every time I add a thumbnail I have to type in the new image number 4 times (for the title and the sources of the 3 image sizes).

Isn't there a way I could just put in the image number once (as an ID or something) and have a javascript interpret that to assign the title and the three links?

Comment: yes, you have the right idea.  The principle is called DRY - *Don't repeat yourself*.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you think about a function to return the desired HTML?

```
function getImageThumb(src, title) {
    return $('<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="' + title + '" rel="{gallery: \'gal1\', smallimage: \'./Vol4/Small/' + src + '.jpg\', largeimage: \'./Vol4/Large/' + src + '.jpg\'}">' +
             '<img src="./Vol4/Thumbs/' + src + '.jpg" alt="' + title + '" width="94" height="150" border="0" /></a>');
}
```

So you can create each thumb like:

```
$("#container").append(getImageThumb('tafel_462', 'Plate 462'));
$("#container").append(getImageThumb('another_img', 'An Example'));
```

Comment: A beautiful solution!  Simple, elegant, and functional.  I was even able to streamline it a bit more by putting the "tafel" and "Plate" bits into the function and only using a single variable for the number.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
Your `a` html should have two attributes, let's say `data-imgsrc`, and `data-gallery`, and remove the a's `rel` attribute and the img's `src` attribute like this:

```
<a  href='javascript:void(0);' title="Plate 462" data-gallery="gal1" data-imgsrc="tafel_462.jpg">
<img width="94" height="150" border="0" /></a>
```

Then you'd do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[data-imgsrc]").each(function(){  //Customize your selector
     var imgsrc = $(this).attr("data-imgsrc");
     var relObj = {
        "gallery": $(this).attr("data-gallery"),
        "smallimage": "./Vol4/Small/"+imgsrc,
        "largeimage": "./Vol4/Large/"+imgsrc
     };
     $(this).attr("rel", JSON.stringify(relObj));
     $(this).find("img").attr("src", "Vol4/Thumbs/"+imgsrc);
  });
});
```

If your gallery isn't variable, you could remove the `data-gallery` attribute and just put 'gallery1' in the js.

That's it.
Hope this helps. Cheers